# MySQL Unknown column in where clause but column exists

Tags: mysql, sql, join, sql-update

So it seems some people have had this problem before, but searching didn't turn up an answer for my case.

I'm running

```
 UPDATE ProdCosts SET PercentCost = ((ProdCosts.PieceCost/totalprodcost.sumpiececost)*100)
 WHERE totalprodcost.ProdNo=ProdCosts.ProdNo;
 AND ProdCosts.PieceCost > 0;
```

and getting the error

```
MySQL said: Documentation
#1054 - Unknown column 'totalprodcost.ProdNo' in 'where clause'
```

DESCRIBE totalprodcost shows:

```
Field   Type    Null    Key     Default     Extra
ProdNo  int(11) YES         NULL    
sumpiececost    double  YES         NULL
```

I can't figure this out.  It seems simple enough.  What gives?

Answer (score 0):

Join the tables on `UPDATE` statement,

```
UPDATE  ProdCosts a
        INNER JOIN totalprodcost b
            ON b.ProdNo = a.ProdNo
SET     a.PercentCost = ((a.PieceCost/b.sumpiececost)*100)
WHERE   a.PieceCost > 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
UPDATE ProdCosts, totalprodcost SET ProdCosts.PercentCost = ((ProdCosts.PieceCost/totalprodcost.sumpiececost)*100) WHERE totalprodcost.ProdNo=ProdCosts.ProdNo AND ProdCosts.PieceCost > 0;
```